# Why am I getting a Null reference exception for a Slider value changed event that happens each time the page loads

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to creating Windows Phone 7 Apps, I have added a slider to my page to which i have customized the look but when i load the page in the emulator before the page even loads I get a "NullReferenceException" I thought this was because I had not initialized the slider so i changed the settings method to

```
public settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sldPassLegnth.Value = (double)3;
    }
```

The value changed event simply looks like this:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        double d;
        d = sldPassLegnth.Value;
    }
```

The xaml for the slider is:

```
<Slider Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}" Margin="24,75,22,352" Name="sldPassLegnth" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Background="Black" Foreground="#FF3399FF" Maximum="15" Minimum="3" />
```

Any insight into this would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        double d;
        d = e.NewValue;
    }
```